# Keeping Image URLs behind a authentication wall

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a website in rails where 100% of it's content is behind an authentication barrier.

Is there a way to have the Image URLs also behind the authentication wall in rails?
eg www.foo.com/bar.jpg will also ask you to login before it'll display an image

Comment: Are you using an authentication framework like Devise?

Answer (score 1):

solved it:

psudocode:

routes.rb:

```
get '/image/:id' => 'image_container#show_image'
```

image_containers_controller.rb:

```
def show_image
        image = ImageContainer.find(params[:id])  
        if #auth logic goes here
               send_file(image.path, type: image.type)
        else
                redirect_to "/no_picture_for_you"
        end
 end
```

image_container.rb:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
  path: ":rails_root/notpublic/images/:id/:basename_:style.:extension"

  def url
      "/image/#{self.id}"
  end
```